# How to tweak tablet settings to install TextSecure?

Tags: textsecure

I would like to install TextSecure on an Android tablet. TextSecure is not currently supported for tablets, and Google Play Store refuses to install it.

How can I tweak the (build.prop?) settings to make Play Store perform the install? I guess I have to make the Play Store believe my tablet is a phone.
I know that TextSecure may not work after the install, but I do want to try.

Comment: You can try to find the APK file for TextSecure and manually install it (there's no check on app installation)

Answer (score 0):

### It seems possible if you have (another) phone number

According to [Wikipedia on Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(software)) (the new name: "In November 2015, the TextSecure and RedPhone applications on Android were merged to become Signal for Android."):

> Signal requires that the user has a phone number for verification.
>   The number does not have to be the same as on the device's SIM card
>   [...]. A number can only be registered to one device at a time.

### How to register

Basically the [FAQ](http://support.whispersystems.org/hc/en-us/articles/213190677-How-can-I-get-Signal-working-with-my-Google-Voice-or-Project-Fi-number-) states you can register with a different number:

> Request a call for the verification number after the two minute timeout.

(Which phone number is shown as sender is also explained in the [FAQ](http://support.whispersystems.org/hc/en-us/articles/215073067).)

### How to build from source (& install)

According to [an old issue on their site](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/issues/127), it was only three commands build and install from source:

```
git pull 
ant release 
adb install -r bin/TextSecure-release.apk
```

### How to download APK (& install) - this maybe risky(!!)

According to [this Github-issue](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/issues/1153):

> multi-device support is on the roadmap

But in the meantime, one can try downloading the APK from other websites, e.g. (same issue):

> You can try sideloading the app via https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/.

This is a user response, I do *not* know if/how trustworthy this site is!!!  But, based on the present [Playstore-link for Signal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms) that link would be: https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms .

#### Why no APK-download or ...store

I do not know, why Signal does not allow installing to a device without SIM (yet), and they may (see quote above). I do know, why they did (do?) not distribute their APK-s for 'wild' installation, see [this issue](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/issues/127):

1. No upgrade channel for effective security
2. No app scanning (possible malware problems)
3. No crash reporting
4. No stats to prioritize development and platforms
5. Not a privacy win
6. To not encourage "allow 3rd party APK-s" by 'naive users'
7. It is still possible to install by building from source for 'power users' (only)